# How to resize height of dropdown menu - CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize dropdown menu with css, but something is wrong with my css. I need to resize the height to make it look normal. Please, look at the screenshot.
Here is my CSS:

```
ul#nav {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background: #ffffff;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

ul#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 8;
}

ul#nav li:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
}

ul#nav li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444444;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

ul#nav li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li ul{
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

ul#nav li ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border-color: transparent transparent #eeeeee transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;  
  margin-left: -8px;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}


ul#nav li:hover ul{
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
}

ul#nav li ul li{
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 100%:
    white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}


ul#nav li ul li:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}

ul#nav li ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
}

ul#nav li ul li a{
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform none! important;
}
```

I'm trying to resize: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUvo3.jpg

Comment: Would you mind creating a JSFiddle with your HTML, CSS and JS? That would help a lot :) - it is most likely caused by absolute positioning or float not being cleared.

Comment: Could you provide your related HTML code?

Comment: Sure, Apologize, that' my first time creating JFSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/anxsrg3r/#&togetherjs=ASAJoPySTa

Comment: Hi Thank you for help! I have another struggle: How do I change distance between lines, not affecting distance btw different links?  http://imgur.com/VpkBcsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `height` property to your `ul#nav li ul` selector.

Like so:

```
ul#nav li ul{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    height:200px;/*Note the change here. Edit the px to whatever you need */
    top: 34;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @averty No problem at all, please don't forget to click the check mark next to my answer so people with a similar issue can quickly find the solution

Comment: Please ask a new question, this question regards the height problem, which has been resolved, editing this or asking something through comments doesn't go well with the SO community @averty

Comment: Yes, I know, the system just doesn't allow me to ask another question

Comment: @averty SO doesn't allow rapid asking of questions you'll have to wait 90 minutes after posting a question, which means you'll have to wait another 50 minutes before you can ask another question

Answer (score 1):

Try editing **line-height** in **ul#nav li a**.